# how to avoid implicit conversion of arguments leading to infinite recursion?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-functions

I have a formatting method that I adapted from [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template).

I have reduced it to just function calls and a print

It works when the formatting string (first argument) is a `const char *`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

// base
std::string format(const char *s)
{
    printf("** %s\n",s);
    return "";
}
// recursive, should parse each argument and print the formatted string
template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::string format(const char *s, T value, Args... args)
{
    printf("** %s\n",s);  // dummy
    return "";
}

int main()
{
   format("foo");   
   printf("yay!\n");
}
```

now I'd like to pass a `std::string` to `format`, I have to do:

```
std::string s = "foo";
format(s.c_str());
```

I'd like to do

```
format(s);
```

So I have added this

```
// recursive
template<typename... Args>
std::string format(const std::string &s,Args... args)
{
  return format(s.c_str(), args...);
}
```

But when I pass the string directly as `std::string` it crashes. Debugging shows an infinite recursion. Difficult to debug templates with `std::string` constructions, but my guess is that

```
return format(s.c_str(), args...);
```

calls itself, because `const char *` implicitly converts as a `std::string`.

Here's the full non-working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

// recursive
template<typename... Args>
std::string format(const std::string &s,Args... args)
{
  return format(s.c_str(), args...);
}


// base
std::string format(const char *s)
{
    printf("** %s\n",s);
    return "";
}
// recursive, should parse each argument and print the formatted string
template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::string format(const char *s, T value, Args... args)
{
    printf("** %s\n",s);  // dummy
    return "";
}

int main()
{
   std::string s = "foo";
   format(s);   
   printf("yay!\n");  // crashes before that
}
```

I could ditch `const char *` version altogether and go full `std::string` but I would like to avoid to build a string when a string literal is passed.

So how to keep the ability to pass either `const char *` directly or `std::string` as first argument ?

Comment: Change the declaration order like https://compiler-explorer.com/z/7boq5xncr ?

Comment: @songyuanyao OK, now I am intrigued. Why the {bleeep} should declaration order matter, and is this *defined* behavior?

Comment: @DevSolar Yes, in OP's code when calling `format` only the function itself is visible, name lookup can't find other functions declared later.

Comment: it probably would not matter in a C++ code file (not header) but since those are templates, everything should be defined in the "header" to be used outside, or it could not be inlined by gcc, so order matters, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your recursive version does not see any declarations to which it could delegate in its `return` statement.

This is the uppermost declaration and definition you have in your code:

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
std::string format(const std::string &s,Args... args)
{
    return format(s.c_str(), args...);
}
```

It doesn't "see" any other candidates, thus it will always call itself recursively.

You can fix it by introducing a declaration to your base case above it. Or moving said case there including its implementation:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

// base
std::string format(const char *s)
{
    printf("** %s\n",s);
    return "";
}

// recursive
template<typename... Args>
std::string format(const std::string &s,Args... args)
{
    return format(s.c_str(), args...);
}

// recursive, should parse each argument and print the formatted string
template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::string format(const char *s, T value, Args... args)
{
    printf("** %s\n",s);  // dummy
    return "";
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "foo";
    format(s);
    printf("yay!\n");  // crashes before that
}
```

Output:

> ```
> ** foo
> yay!
> ```

Comment: in my real code the base case was already at the top (so I managed to flunk my [mcve] ...), but I was inserting the `std::string` part before the `const char *` template, so moving the `std::string` flavour at the bottom had the desired effect. Simple as that, thanks a lot.